# JavaScript fetch API and Python Flask header issue

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I'm trying to POST a JSON payload to a Flask server running on `localhost:8080`.

**Javascript**

```
    fetch(SERVER_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({"hello": "world"})
    });
```

I'm using Python Flask for my server, and I just want to print the received JSON on the server side.

**Python Flask**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/route', methods = ['POST'])
def routeHandler():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    return 'got it'

app.run(port = 8080)
```

The print statement is triggered, but `data` is `None`. After reading the Flask API documentation, I know that one of the reasons why `data` could be `None` is when the correct content type is not set on the request. To check this, I made the following change

```
 data = request.get_json(force = True)
```

which bypasses the `is_json()` check and continues parsing. This worked, suggesting there's something wrong with my headers. However, I have ensured that my `fetch` request is consistent with the API documentation so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I have sent the same request from Postman and it is successfully received on the server even without `force = True`. The only header generated in Postman is `Content-Type: application/json`.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What happens when you try to access `data['hello']`?

Comment: data is None so I cannot index into it

Comment: `wireshark` or `tcpdump` or `tcpflow` may help to see what happened in the network. you can debug into flask to see what you get from the request.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same frustration, and you question helped solve my issue, by forcing get_json()

I did notice that the difference between my implementation and yours is:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app)
```

https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/